# Importar CSV para a database do Django

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, django, csv

Tenho uma database em CSV e queria importar para os meus models do Django, o CSV está com essa estrutura:

```
  NAME,CLUB,LEAGUE,POSITION,RATING,PACE,SHOOTING,PASSING,DRIBBLING,DEFENDING,PHYSICAL,LOADDATE
  Tore Reginiussen,Rosenborg BK,Tippeligaen,CB,82,65,53,60,68,84,79,2018-04-14 08:37:48
```

Daí tenho os seguintes models no projeto:

```
   class Player(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        league = models.ForeignKey('League', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        club = models.ForeignKey('Club', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        attributes = models.ForeignKey('Attribute', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
          return self.name

    class League(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

        def __str__(self):
          return self.name

    class Club(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        league = models.ForeignKey('League', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
           return self.name

    class Attribute(models.Model):
        pace = models.IntegerField()
        shooting = models.IntegerField()
        passing = models.IntegerField()
        dribbling = models.IntegerField()
        defending = models.IntegerField()
        physical = models.IntegerField()
        position = models.CharField(max_length=4)
        overall = models.IntegerField()

        def __str__(self):
            return '%s %s'%(self.overall, self.position)
```

Qual seria a melhor maneira de importar corretamente os dados do CSV pra minha tabela?

Comment: Guilherme, Existe o import/export talvez poderia ser útil para seu problema.
Veja se o link abaixo pode ser útil. http://abhishekchhibber.com/django-importing-a-csv-file-to-database-models/

Comment: tentei isso e nao consegui fazer funcionar :(

Answer (score -2):

Para trabalhar com arquivos CSV recomendo usar o [pyexcel](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel), é bastante flexível, alem de possibilitar o uso de outros formatos como xls e xlsx.

Para importar o arquivo você deve usar o método `get_sheet` (que suporta qualquer formato).

Caso precise integrar apenas com CSV, você ainda pode usar alguns plugins como o [pyexcel-io](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-io). Que facilita bastante a integração com outros formatos.

Na [documentação do plugin](http://io.pyexcel.org/en/latest/plaincsv.html#read-from-a-csv-file) você encontra exemplos bem práticos do funcionamento.